# C# .Net Core send DataSet to asmx wcf web service as ArrayOfXElement

Tags: c#, .net-core, soap

I am writing a .Net Core 3.1 Web Api wrapper to a WCF ASMX Web Service. The service has a method that takes an input parameter of DataSet which in .Net Core 3.1 is interpreted as ArrayOfXElement. I am attempting to convert the DataSet which contains a single DataTable to ArrayOfXElement but cannot figure out how to get the 2 nodes (column definition and table).

My current code is as follows:

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet("NewDataSet");
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("aggregate_Loan.Comments");
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CommentText", Type.GetType("System.String")));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CommentType", Type.GetType("System.String")));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DateTimeAdded", Type.GetType("System.DateTime")));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UserKey", Type.GetType("System.String")));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CommentTypeKey", Type.GetType("System.String")));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UserName", Type.GetType("System.String")));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ReasonID", Type.GetType("System.String")));
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "My test", null, null, "123", "456", null, 5 });
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);

    var container = new XElement("container");
    using (var writer = container.CreateWriter())
    {
        ds.WriteXml(writer, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
    }
```

In this case, I have generated XElement, not ArrayOfXElement. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method that worked best was to modify the Reference.cs file generated by Visual Studio to change the ArrayOfXElement to DataSet.

There is a drawback to this approach in that any modifications to the service will result in having to reapply that logic instead of just refreshing the service reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet("NewDataSet");
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("aggregate_Loan.Comments");
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CommentText", Type.GetType("System.String")));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CommentType", Type.GetType("System.String")));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DateTimeAdded", Type.GetType("System.DateTime")));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UserKey", Type.GetType("System.String")));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CommentTypeKey", Type.GetType("System.String")));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UserName", Type.GetType("System.String")));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ReasonID", Type.GetType("System.String")));
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "My test", null, null, "123", "456", null, 5 });
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);

            List<XElement> elements = new List<XElement>();
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.AsEnumerable())
            {
                XElement newElement = new XElement("ABC", new object[] {
                    new XElement("CommentText", row["CommentText"]),
                    new XElement("CommentType", row["CommentType"]),
                    new XElement("DateTimeAdded", row["DateTimeAdded"]),
                    new XElement("UserKey", row["UserKey"]),
                    new XElement("CommentTypeKey", row["CommentTypeKey"]),
                    new XElement("UserName", row["UserName"]),
                    new XElement("ReasonID", row["ReasonID"])
                });
                elements.Add(newElement);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @jdweng, this response returns a collection of XElement which is quite different from a ArrayOfXElement. .Net Core does not understand what a DataSet is when it is passed as either an input parameter or an output from a Soap request and instead creates an ArrayOfXlement. This has 2 nodes, the first is a description of the columns and the 2nd begins as <diffgr:diffgram and contains all of the rows of data. For reference, see https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/4294 and https://www.developerfusion.com/article/84402/serializing-datasets/